# Is A* capable of handling multiple levels (e.g.: multi-story buildings)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, path-finding, voxel

I have a 3D voxel game and I'm trying to find best fitting pathfinding algorithm to use. I've been wondering if the A* algorithm is capable of handling multiple levels, for example a multi-story building and find routes through staircases or ladders.

Is this possible with A* or should I use something else?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a graph algorithm, so, yes. I suggest reading up on how graphs work.

Comment: I can reinforce what @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft said, funny enough i'm just learning about it :), unity has a quality asset tho: https://arongranberg.com/astar/

Answer (score 0):

Any path-finding algorithms(uniform or non-uniform) can be used as long as you use them right. You have to decide first on what kind of path-finding you want to use depending on what you want to achieve.

Uniform or graph algorithms can have a lot of overhead for a multi-story building due to excessive nodes. (assuming that you are building the whole building all at once)

Non-uniforms are way slower than graph algorithms but doesn't have much of a overhead.

It really depends on what you want your characters to do, and how you will optimize it.

A* is fast, but you might want to check out some iterations of A* like jump point system.

Comment: [JPS](https://www.gamedev.net/articles/programming/artificial-intelligence/jump-point-search-fast-a-pathfinding-for-uniform-cost-grids-r4220/) is great, highly recommend. The real issue is that for multistory buildings you can't just let the pathfinder loose, it'll probably tell you to go out the window and scale the wall (and/or fly). You have to set up your grid correctly and assume that you can't travel vertically unless the floor does (eg stairs). And You'll need to weight your A\* to *search for stairs* if the agent needs to take them, *then* the goal.

Answer (score 0):

[Try using the NavMesh component based workflow first](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/NavMesh-BuildingComponents.html). If there is a nice staircase behaviour that can be efficiently and automatically used, NavMesh will find it.

Otherwise, you will need to use something called hierarchical search. [Read an example here.](https://factorio.com/blog/post/fff-317)

Comment: NavMeshes are great for static world, but as this is a voxel game the player can change anything anytime. As I know NavMeshes require baking. If the player decides to e. G.: build a wall, then every time a block is placed, the appropriate chunk of the world gets updated, therefore the Navmesh has to be updated as well and causing the game to be imperformant. Tough I don't know if I'm completely right.

Comment: Yes, try it first. In reality your agents don't necessarily need the path right away. Additionally you do not need to recompute the whole navmesh for small changes, read the docs carefully and think about how you would use "cells" of navmeshes.